# Replace Existing Values on one Tab With Values From a Table on Another tab

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to find a way to replace all values on the second tab of an Excel workbook with values from a table in a different tab 1 cell to the right of the corresponding value. On Sheet1 there are 2 columns. 1 is called ID and the second is called New ID. On Sheet2 there is a column called ID. I am looking for a way so that when I run a macro the values on Sheet2 will be replaced by the corresponding New ID from Sheet1. For example, on Sheet2 the first ID is ABC. On Sheet1 the corresponding New ID value for ABC is 123. I'd like the VBA script to replace all ABCs on Sheet2 with 123. I need this for varying amounts of data.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCT2H.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnFOv.png)

So far I've tried the following but it won't change the cells
Sub Test1()

```
Dim N As Long, L As Long
Dim rLook As Range

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
aryA = Range("A2:A" & N)
aryB = Range("B2:B" & N)

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Set rLook = Range("A2:A" & N)
For L = 1 To N
    rLook.Replace aryA(L, 1), aryB(L, 1)
Next L
```

End Sub

When I run the macro it only changes the same number of rows as Sheet1 so I am left with the following:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Punqh.png)

After I run this I get an error that says subscript is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is basically that you reuse N, which is the number of rows from sheet1 to define the range on sheet2.

So my advise is to use more explicit names for variables that explain what the variable "contains".

Furthermore if you don't use the implicit `Cells(xxx)` but the explicit one `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` you can omit the selection of the sheets (and by that reduce the possibility for errors referencing the wrong range).

Plus: you can read both columns of sheet1 into one array

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub updateSheet2IDs()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim cntRowsSheet1 As Long
Dim arrSource As Variant
With wsSource
    cntRowsSheet1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'array includes both columns: arrsource(1,1) = A2, arrsource(1,2) = B2
    arrSource = .Range("A2:B" & cntRowsSheet1)
End With

Dim cntRowsSheet2 As Long, rgTarget As Range
With wsTarget
    cntRowsSheet2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rgTarget = .Range("A2:A" & cntRowsSheet2)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 1)   'ubound gives you the upper bound of the array
        rgTarget.Replace arrSource(i, 1), arrSource(i, 2)
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

You could omit the whole "cntRows"-stuff by using `currentregion` - which returns the area around one cell that is surrounded by empty rows and columns (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion).

That means that `wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion`will return all cells until the first empty row and until the first empty column - I assume this is exactly what your are looking for. The same for sheet2 as well.

To omit the first row, you can use `offset`:

`set rgTarget = wsTarget.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1)`

The code then looks like

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub updateSheet2IDs()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")


'array includes both columns: arrsource(1,1) = A2, arrsource(1,2) = B2
Dim arrSource As Variant
arrSource = wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1)


Dim rgTarget As Range
Set rgTarget = wsTarget.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 1)   'ubound gives you the upper bound of the array
    rgTarget.Replace arrSource(i, 1), arrSource(i, 2)
Next

End Sub
```